# Switch sim cards?

Tags: nexus-5, sim-card, moto-x, gsm, cdma

Up to about 3 weeks ago, I had a Motorola Moto X running Android 5.1 with Verizon/CDMA . Then I switched to a Nexus 5 running Android 6 with Ting/GSM. The Ting service is terrible it turns out, so I am probably going to switch back to Verizon. I do like the Nexus 5 much better than the Moto X. Can I use the CDMA SIM Card from the Moto X in the Nexus 5 on my switch back to Verizon?

Comment: The Nexus 5 does not support CDMA or the proper LTE bands for Verizon service, if you have the Nexus 5x it will work but not the original Nexus 5.